# Mysql query returning too many rows

Tags: php, mysql

so I have 3 tables all inner joined, I am trying to put discussions with the discussion topic on my main page, with the users name and the latest discussion message on the main page as well.

THE PROBLEM: The query is returning all messages attached to all the discussions.....I just need the last message associated with the discussion returned.

I have been at this all day and cant figure it out. I have tried group by but that just gave me an error on mysqli_fetch_array

Here is my code

```
$discussionquery = "SELECT discussion_messages.discussion_id, user_profile.first_name, user_profile.last_name, discussion_messages.message_text, case_discussion.discussion_title 
                        FROM `user_profile` 
                        INNER JOIN discussion_messages 
                        ON (user_profile.user_id = discussion_messages.user_id) 
                        INNER JOIN case_discussion 
                        ON (case_discussion.discussion_id = discussion_messages.discussion_id) 
                        WHERE discussion_messages.case_id = '$thecaseid' 
                        ORDER BY discussion_messages.message_id DESC";
    $discussionquerydata = mysqli_query($dbc, $discussionquery); 

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($discussionquerydata)) {
    $discussion_id = $row2['discussion_id'];

    ?>
    <!-- Begin Recent Discussions -->  
    <div class="row">
      <a href="discussion.php?newfact=$thecaseid'>">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
          <img src="img/client4.jpg" class="profile_picture img-rounded">
          <?php echo '<h6 class="discussionname">' . $row2['first_name'] . ' ' . $row2['last_name'] . '</h6>';?>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-10 discussion_title">
         <?php echo '<h5><a href="discussion.php?caseid='.$thecaseid.'&did='.$discussion_id.'"> '.$row2['discussion_title'].'</a> -'. $row2['message_text'];?></h5>           
        <h6 class="pull-right">Dec. 25</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    };
```

Comment: `ORDER BY discussion_messages.message_id DESC LIMIT 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need logic to find the last message for each discussion.  There is more than one way to write this condition.

The following does it using a `not exists` clause.  This checks that there are no messages with a larger id for the discussion:

```
SELECT dm.discussion_id, up.first_name, up.last_name, dm.message_text, cd.discussion_title 
FROM `user_profile` up INNER JOIN
     discussion_messages dm
     ON (user_profile.user_id = dm.user_id) INNER JOIN
     case_discussion cd
     ON (cd.discussion_id = dm.discussion_id) 
WHERE dm.case_id = '$thecaseid' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from discussion_messages dm2
                  where dm2.discussion_id = dm.discussion_id and
                        dm2.message_id > dm.message_id
                )
ORDER BY dm.message_id DESC;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, Thanks for the help, I am still getting  ...mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result... is there a good resource for explaining how to use logic with mysql statements? or would you be able to delve a little deeper into how this solution works so I could take it from there?

Comment: @SamBrody . . . That is an error at the php level, not the query level.  Does the query return an error?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\casekeeper\case.php on line 86

Comment: This is he line it is failing on `code`while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($discussionquerydata)) { `code`

Comment: I noticed that everytime I try to use aliases I get the same error, is there any setting I need to adjust to change that?

Comment: @SamBrody . . . I noticed that the `select` subquery was missing a column after the `select` (I just added the 1).  That would have caused a compiler error.

Comment: If I remove the sub query It displays the messages (without limiting them) so I think the problem is with the subquery

Comment: and not exist (
                                                select discussion_messages.message_text
                                                from discussion_messages discussion_messages2
                                                where discussion_messages2.discussion_id = discussion_messages.discussion_id and
                                                      discussion_messages2.message_id > discussion_messages.message_id
                                              )

Comment: @SamBrody . . . The code looks right, if a bit verbose.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion, use table aliases.  The amount of total code will be smaller and easier to understand.  Use the limit clause to return 1 row.

```
$discussionquery = "
 SELECT 
   m.discussion_id, 
   u.first_name, 
   u.last_name, 
   d.message_text, 
   c.discussion_title                         
 FROM `user_profile` as u                       
 INNER JOIN discussion_messages as m
   ON (u.user_id = m.user_id) 
 INNER JOIN case_discussion c
   ON (m.discussion_id = c.discussion_id) 
 WHERE 
   m.case_id = '$thecaseid' 
 ORDER BY 
   m.message_id DESC
 LIMIT 1";
```